# How to execute a long running subprocess inside celery task?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, celery

I have the following code where I am running a shell script using subprocess inside a celery task. It's not working as in I don't get an error or any forward progress, or any output from the celery task:

The following is the code to execute the task:

```
def run_shell_command(command_line):
    command_line_args = shlex.split(command_line)

    logging.info('Subprocess: "' + command_line + '"')

    try:
        command_line_process = subprocess.Popen(
            command_line_args,
            shell=True,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        )

        for l in iter(command_line_process.stdout.readline,b''):
            print l.strip()

        command_line_process.communicate()
        command_line_process.wait()

    except (OSError, subprocess.CalledProcessError) as exception:
        logging.info('Exception occured: ' + str(exception))
        logging.info('Subprocess failed')
        return False
    else:
        # no exception was raised
        logging.info('Subprocess finished')

    return True
```

It's called from within a task:

```
@app.task
def execute(jsonConfig, projectName, tagName, stage, description):

     command = 'python ' + runScript + ' -c ' + fileName
     run_shell_command(command)
```

Here the python "runScript" is in itself calling subprocesses, and executes a long running task. What could be the problem

The logging level has been set to INFO :

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='celery-execution.log',level=logging.INFO)
```

The celery worker is started as follow:

```
celery -A celery_worker worker --loglevel=info
```

I can see the subprocess being started:

```
[2016-05-03 01:08:55,126: INFO/Worker-2] Subprocess: "python runScript.py -c data/confs/Demo-demo14-1.conf"
```

I can also see the subprocess running in the background using a ps -ef, however this is a compute/memory intensive workload and it does not seem to be actually using any cpu or memory which makes me believe that nothing is really happening and it's stuck.

Comment: What is the logging level on the celery worker?  It sounds odd that you're getting no feedback from celery.  Can you confirm other tasks are running as expected?

Comment: @ThomasTu: Please check the updates and suggest. I can see the process starting even using ps -ef, but it doesn't seem to be actually running since it's not using any cpu or memory. I can also confirm that there is no output.

Comment: Does `python runScript.py -c data/confs/Demo-demo14-1.conf` work on its own?

Comment: yes it does. I also applied strace to the process which is started using pid from ps -ef, and i find it is stuck on the following syscall: wait4(-1,

Comment: @ThomasTu: Does it matter if the python runScript itself calls subprocesses?

Comment: It really shouldn't -- subprocess is just a python wrapper for launching a new processes.  I thought it might be the deadlock issue mentioned in the [subprocess docs regarding wait and setting stdout=PIPE](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait).  I don't think there's any reason to need to call communicate and then wait -- could you try taking out `command_line_process.wait()`?